# Protractor tests Fail when i run in headless mode on Chrome

Tags: jasmine, protractor

My protractor tests **run ok with chrome browser**, but fails when i run them in **headless** mode

protractor config

```
  directConnect: false,
  capabilities:
    {
      browserName: "chrome",
      chromeOptions: {
        args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080","--no-sandbox" ]
      }
    },
```

chrome Version: 90.0.4430.85
Chrome Driver: chromedriver_90.0.4430.24

My App runs on an insecure URL (ie. every time i have tests to accept security exceptions )

Comment: what kind of error do you get

Comment: this.ClickCloseAutosweepListAlt = function () {
        element.isPresent().then(function (elm) {
            if (elm) {
                element.click()
                console.log(`... Close button Clicked`)
            } else {
                expect(elm).toBe(true)
                console.log(`... Close button Not found ***`)
            }
        })
    } ////

Comment: ... Close button Not found *** is displaed on the terminal